# execute perl from specman

Tags: c, perl, specman

I need to call a Perl script from an E test that I wrote. I need to create an ini file-invoke C script that will create a config file which I need for the test I'm writing. I want the test to invoke  the Perl which will handle the ini->C->config process, and then proceed with the test. any ideas?

Comment: What is `E`? Do you **really** need E to call Perl, and Perl to call C (what is a C script?) to create a config file? **Simplify** is my suggestion.

Comment: "e" is a hardware verification language. Its most common implementation ( only, probably.. ) is Cadence's Specman.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specman

Comment: FYI, there is no Perl API for Specman.  Only a C and C++ API for compiling in your code with Specman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do system calls or shell commands with functions `system` or `output_from`.  This can be used to execute arbitrary commands, including invocations of Perl.  The `system` function returns the return value of the shell call, whereas `output_from` returns the standard out ( and maybe standard error... check your docs..).

Examples:

```
var ret := system("echo hello world");
```

prints to Specman screen/log file

```
hello world
```

Whereas `output_from` is used like:

```
var std_out := output_from("echo hello world");
print std_out;
```

and prints:

```
std_out = "hello world"
```

The functions take a string, so you can build up the arguments using the `append()` and `appendf()` functions.

Small aside: You can talk directly to the simulator command line interface using `simulator_command(cmd_str)`.  I've used this one before for talking with Synopsys' VCS

```
simulator_command("quit");
```

Comment: is there any way to get both the output and the return value at the same time?

Comment: `output_from_check()` - it performs just like `output_from()`, except if the command returns non zero, it will throw an error.  If you need to be able to handle the error condition, then you'll need to wrapper it with a  `try { } else { }` exception handler.  This wont allow you to get the exact return value, but it will allow you to detect and handle failed system calls.